# How can I improve my question to receive an answer?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

My question has been down-voted with no comments and has remained dormant all weekend. I would really like an answer to the question, so I'm willing to post a bounty on the question. However, given that it's been down-voted, I would like to improve whatever is wrong with the question. If it still doesn't receive an answer, I will put a bounty on it.

The question: [How to compile localization DLLs (MyLibrary.resources.dll) into a single DLL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22874634/how-to-compile-localization-dlls-mylibrary-resources-dll-into-a-single-dll)

How can I improve this question to receive an answer? (The down-vote is secondary.)

Comment: It seems like a decent question. The downvote may be unrelated to the lack of answer. The downvote, who knows, don't sweat it. The lack of answers could be caused simply by nobody knowing the answer. I'm not a C# programmer though, so I can't speak for things like whether or not it is an obvious, trivial question, etc.

Comment: I gave it an upvote but you might want to add (with a codesample) how you plan to use the default ResourceManager in your required scenario. Because I don't think there is an out-of-the-box solution. And that would explain the downvote (expressing not useful)

Comment: @JasonC, I assumed that people wouldn't look at my question due to the downvote. The question says "6 views" and that hasn't changed the entire weekend, even after the recent visits. Apparently I should ignore that number. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @DavidEnglund Yeah; most people who answer questions here are used to overlooking a couple of downvotes; it's not unusual. You could add a [bounty](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work), too, if you want to attract attention at the cost of reputation points.

Comment: People just cast downvotes to have their own question to be substituted which was posted in well-timed fashion. Consequently a well-timed downvote will save the day for them.

Comment: Its also pretty rare for people to want to answer its not possible. Because it will not get any reputation and the OP will just likely be offended, because now its this answers reason why nobody posts a better answer. Even if its the best possible answer.

Comment: @joojaa I actually disagree on that. I frequently see that as an answer, I have never heard of anybody having doubts about posting it. I know, personally, at least, I have no qualms about saying "it's not possible" when I can verify that it isn't. I also try to post alternatives. If you are withholding "it's  not possible" answers, you should not be; if something isn't possible, keeping that a secret from the OP does them (and everybody else with a similar question) a disservice.